# Are these two lines are same or different?

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon

I am new to Katalon Studio. I find this line to open a website:

`WebUI.openBrowser('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask')`

and also I find this line:

`DriverFactory.getWebDriver().get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask')`

Are these two lines are same or different?

Comment: I found the answer and posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between these two lines is that `WebUI.openBrowser()` opens a **new browser instance** and navigates to the specified URL, while `DriverFactory.getWebDriver().get()` navigates to the specified URL using an **existing browser instance**.